# Support for Kanna framework in Swift 3.0?

Tags: cocoapods, swift3

After migrating my project from Swift 2.2 to 3.0 I get an error message on the Kanna framework, saying that

> Module file was created by an older version of the compiler. Rebuild Kanna and try again

Have I done anything wrong or does the Kanna framework not work under Swift 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a now a working version for Swift 3.0, using carthage. Everything is described here:
[Kanna github](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna)

Answer (score 2):

To use Kanna library (CocoaPods) you need add it to your *Podfile*:

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'Kanna', git: 'https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna.git', branch: 'swift3.0'
```

then in terminal:

```
rm Podfile.lock (if exist)
pod init
pod update
pod install
```

Take tutorial from [here](http://swift-hacks.blogspot.com/2016/09/swift-30-tutorial-how-to-add-framework.html)